# .bind/.unbind event after initial prettyphoto.open funcation is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I am using .appened to add some HTML to a div in markup that is being outputted when prettyphoto light-box clone opens.

I am trying to figure out how to only load the appended HTML to the light-box once and not every time the a new image in the gallery is viewed by using the back/next button.

From what I have found this would be done by using .bind/.unbind but writing this function does not seem to work.

I am using the following even handler inside the prettyphoto open function

```
$.prettyPhoto.open=function(event){

$(".pbdog-gAd").append('<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="' + prettyLink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + prettyAd + '" width="468" height="60" alt="" /></a></p>');
```

Which results in the desired output...

[image]

My problem is that each time the next/previous buttons are clicked it runs the script again and adds an additional ad image below the current one, as seen below. It keeps doing this until prettyphoto eventually crashes

[image]

From what I can understand I need to write a function that will call this event the first time but not each time the next/previous button is clicked

I have tried the following with no luck

```
$(".pbdog-gAd").bind("click", function( event ) {
$(".pbdog-gAd").append('<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="' + prettyLink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + prettyAd + '" width="468" height="60" alt="" /></a></p>');
$(this).unbind( event );
});
```

Doing the above seems to make prettyphoto ignore this function all together. Doing the below seems to break prettyphoto

```
$.prettyPhoto.bind("click", function( event ) {
$(".pbdog-gAd").append('<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="' + prettyLink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + prettyAd + '" width="468" height="60" alt="" /></a></p>');
$(this).unbind( event );
});
```

I obviously don't understand what I am doing here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this was to just use .removeClass after the .append has been run. This stopped the image from being loaded a 2nd time and also removed the class so no formatting is applied to the space if no values are loaded for during the .append process.

```
$(".pbdog-gAd").append('<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="' + JprettyLink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + JprettyAd + '" width="468" height="60" alt="" /></a></p>');
$(".pbdog-gAd").removeClass("pbdog-gAd");
```